# Python After 5:00pm

Tags: python

When a function runs I need it to check the current system time and if its past 5:00pm to do something.

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
if current_time > {code to represent 17:00 hours}:
    do stuff
```

Edit for clarification:
Orders are being sent into my software which handles the picking/packing of orders in a distribution center. If the order is sent into the system after 5:00 then that order needs to get flagged so that it isn't "picked" until the following day. So the function needs to be run as orders are "imported"

Comment: Far easier would be to use `cron` or Windows scheduled tasks.......

Comment: Orders are being sent into my software which handles the picking/packing of orders in a distribution center. If the order is sent into the system after 5:00 then that order needs to get flagged so that it isn't "picked" until the following day. So the function needs to be run as orders are "imported"

Comment: This is a typical "I did not read the docs" kind of question: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Comment: I don't know why the downvote.  simple question with a simple answer;  Maybe it's a duplicate, but not of the question linked.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - yes, I think both David and I misread the question in the same way ;^)

Comment: I'm confused on the down votes too. Granted i should have looked at the docs closer (i was over thinking this for sure) but I could easily see someone else searching for an answer to this. With two perfectly good solutions already posted.

Comment: Well, on the bright side; empty downvotes are a great way to earn sympathetic upvotes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if datetime.datetime.now().hour >= 17:
    pass
```

Comment: I had originally marked TokenMacGuys answer as correct but have switched to this answer simply because it easier to read.

Comment: Dear downvoters, could you please leave a comment? I'd like to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's easy:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time()
datetime.time(10, 36, 5, 572343)
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time() >= datetime.time(17,0,0)
False
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time() >= datetime.time(8,0,0)
True
```

Comment: wow, I sure didn't expect this to be downvoted... I'm not sure I know what's wrong so that I can fix it.  Can anyone suggest what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Both yours' and CharString's answer do exactly what i want. Between the two answers is one "better" then the other or just two different ways to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: well, mine uses the `datetime.time` class for the comparison.  if you like using classes, that's a plus;  If you dislike classes, maybe it's a minus.  They do the very same thing.

Comment: Mine is just shorter and simpler. And doesn't have the overhead of creating the time object. Its a little bit faster, but not as much as I expected: 4.1 us vs 4.85 us. So you should go with what reads easiest.